# Storing a pointer in NSButton

Tags: objective-c, parameter-passing, nsbutton

I'm programmatically setting up a `NSButton` with a target object and I want to pass another object to the called selector.

As far as I know, I can only pass the `NSButton` instance to a selector, so I'm looking for a way to store a pointer to another object inside of my `NSButton`.

Is that possible or is there another way to do this?

Example:

```
[fooButton setAction:NSSelectorFromString(@"fooSelector:")];
[fooButton setTarget:myTargetHandler]
```

And now, I want to pass "`myObject`" to `myTargetHandler` (`fooSelector:`) when `fooButton` is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered simply subclassing NSButton and adding a property for this? You may even be able to achieve it with a simple category.

There's also a `- (NSInteger)tag` in every UIControl - maybe that works?

Comment: I don't want to subclass and yes, I'm currently struggling around with "tag", but didn't figure out how to pass a pointer as an integer.

Comment: That's probably very dangerous to do, since it will confuse ARC a lot.

Comment: Well I don't use ARC either ;-) but if there is no other correct way to do so, I will subclass it…